# Using Swig in Cmake doesn't link Java properly

Tags: java, c, cmake, swig

I'm trying to link a very simple test C library with Java, using Swig *and* Cmake (required by project). When I run things manually things work fine:

```
$ swig -java AMItest.i
$ gcc -fPIC -c AMItest.c AMItest_wrap.c -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include/linux
$ gcc -shared AMItest.o  AMItest_wrap.o  -W  -o libAMItest_swig.so
$ javac main.java
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. java main
```

My cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
enable_language(C)
project(AMItest)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-ggdb -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wno-unused-function") 
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED COMPONENTS java)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS} .)
swig_add_library(AMItest_swig  LANGUAGE java  SOURCES AMItest.i)
# Optional below
find_package(Java REQUIRED)
add_custom_command(TARGET AMItest_swig COMMAND javac main.java MAIN_DEPENDENCY main.java DEPENDS libAMItest_swig.so BYPRODUCTS main.class)
```

When I try and run:

```
$ cmake . &7 make && LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. java main
java: symbol lookup error: libAMItest_swig.so: undefined symbol: AMItest
$ nm libAMItest_swig.so | grep AMItest
                 U AMItest
0000000000003089 T Java_AMItestJNI_AMItest
```

My main.java:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        System.loadLibrary("AMItest_swig"); // File is libAMItest_swig.so
        int size = 11;
        double[] myArray = new double[size];
        System.out.println(AMItest.AMItest(myArray, 10, 20));
        ...
    }
}
```

And finaly my AMItest.h (the C code is not really relevant here):

```
extern int AMItest(double *Array, int Start, int End);
```

I'm pretty sure it comes from some differences compiling the C code, but comparing the line with `cc` using `make VERBOSE=1` doesn't work as there are too many differences. I probably need some option or include some lib. But whch and how ?

Comment: you may be interested by https://github.com/Mizux/java-native

Comment: `swig_add_library(AMItest_swig` will generate a CMake Target AMItest_swig which is the library so your depends seems odd to me...

Comment: Note, that `add_custom_command(TARGET)` command flow is a [build event](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) and it doesn't accept `MAIN_DEPENDENCY` and `DEPENDS` keywords. Most likely, options for these keywords are simply ignored. So, if you updated `main.java` **after**, e.g. `AMItest.i`, then the resulted `main` is not rebuilt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding `AMItest.c` to swig_add_library like so:

```
swig_add_library(AMItest_swig  LANGUAGE java  SOURCES AMItest.i AMItest.c)
```

as well as replacing the line:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET AMItest_swig COMMAND javac main.java MAIN_DEPENDENCY main.java DEPENDS libAMItest_swig.so BYPRODUCTS main.class)
```

with:

```
include(UseJava)
add_jar(
        Main
        SOURCES main.java
        ENTRY_POINT main
)
add_dependencies(Main AMItest_swig)
```

Then it can be called like this:

```
java -jar Main.jar
```

and the numbers are output correctly, which means that the Dynamic Link Library is built correctly.

To sum up: Your slightly modified CMakeLists.txt would look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
enable_language(C)
project(AMItest)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-ggdb -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wno-unused-function")
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED COMPONENTS java)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS} .)
swig_add_library(AMItest_swig  LANGUAGE java  SOURCES AMItest.i AMItest.c)
# Optional below
find_package(Java REQUIRED)
include(UseJava)
add_jar(
        Main
        SOURCES main.java
        ENTRY_POINT main
)
add_dependencies(Main AMItest_swig)
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks promising (I did not see previous examples with the c file in the `swig_add_library`), but it tries to compile the jar before creating the .so. The order of operations is wrong. It works if I separate manually. How do I ensure `add_jar` is done after `swig_add_library` (there's no DEPENDS in add_jar) ?

Comment: I added `add_dependencies(Main AMItest_swig)` and now everything is peachy. Thanks

Comment: You're right! Interestingly, it is no problem if you build with the command `cmake --build builddir --parallel 3`. However, one does have the dependency problem when using `--parallel 1` or simply calling `make`. Of course your approach  with `add_dependencies` is better. I have updated the answer accordingly. Thanks!